# Unable to import Eclipse plug-in source code in Indigo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

Using the instructions found in [Cannot import eclipse source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522457/cannot-import-eclipse-source-code) , I am unable to import plug-in source code for Eclipse Indigo. The instructions were written for Helios, but it's hard to believe that this would have changed. Is it possible that Indigo stopped including plug-in source code?

Screenshot showing that I have the Eclipse SDK installed:
[image: Eclipse SDK installed]

Screenshot showing that I can Import a plug-in 'As Source Project':
[image: Importing Project with source]

Screenshot showing the lack of source in the imported Project:
[image: Project view lacking source]

Screenshot showing the result of attempting to open a particular class file:
[image: Lack of source attached]

As a workaround, I'll simply be using the Git repositories in the meantime. Any suggestions how to get this to work the way it was intended? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any info in error log regarding the import?

Comment: No, nothing listed in the Error Log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Original answer was totally wrong).

Make sure you have downloaded the [Eclipse Classic](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-371/indigosr1) from the download site. This contains the JDT source. Not all Eclipse editions come with the source code.

Comment: I opened the plugin 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui' as a 'Source Project'. In the following screenshot, you see that the project for 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui' is in fact opened, except that it only includes a jar and resources, but no actual source code.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, Eclipse Classic included the source, while my previously downloaded Eclipse bundle did not.